# Issue mocking a class variable value in java

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, refactoring, mockito

I have a class that has a private class variable initialized like

```
public class MyClass{

    private BusinessObject businessObject = BusinessObjectGenerator.getBusinessObject();

    public MyClass(){

    }

    public Object myMethodToTest(){
    return businessObject.getObject();
    }
}
```

Now, I'm trying to unit test `myMethodToTest` I want to send in a mock object in place of `businessObject`. I use mockito for mocking and use `spy(new MyClass())` for partial mocking but having trouble with mocking the  call to get `businessObject`. 
1. Is it possible to mock the call to the businessObject? If so how?
2. How can I refactor this code to help while writing unit test. Any resources pointing towards this would be of great help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To properly refactor this code you'd:

```
private BusinessObject businessObject;

public void setBusinessObject(BusinessObject instance) {
    businessObject = instance;
}

private BusinessObject getBusinessObject() {
    if (businessObject == null) {
        // represents existing implementation in original code sample
        businessObject = BusinessObjectGenerator.getBusinessObject();
    }
    return businessObject;
}

/* rest of your code */
```

Now you can inject your mock into the class yourself at the test site.

I'd recommend doing this using dependency injection with a framework like [Guice](https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/). It will be worth your time.

Comment: I'd rather use constructor injection than setter injection :)

Comment: Agreed (re: constructor injection).

Comment: @Brice if we use constructor injection, how do we mock the `BusinessObjectGenerator.getBusinessObject();` call? The problem is that we can `spy` only after an object is created.

Comment: I am not familiar enough with Mockito's spy (is it just a proxy?) but the constructor injection is primarily for use in your actual production code execution path; you have a GuiceModule that provides `BusinessObject.class` via a `@Provides public BusinessObject getBusinessObject { BusinessObjectGenerator.getBusinessObject(); }` with the appropriate @Inject-annotated constructor for your class. Your test site code remains the same - you pass your mock or spy into the constructor in lieu of using the @Inject-ed setter.

Comment: You don't need spy (actually I think spy is only for legacy code). Mock business object first and create object under test (constructor injection). Call getter method. And verify - Mockito.verify(mockBusiness).getBusinessObject(). That's all

Comment: @cfeduke `spy` is used around real objects instead of mocks. You construct a real object and then mock just the methods you want.